# find data for a particular month in rails mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, aggregate

i am trying to query the data created in a particular month.

```
@events = Event.aggregates([
                               {
                                   '$project': {
                                       _id: 1,
                                       created_at: 1,
                                       'month': {'$month': '$created_at'}
                                   },
                               },
                               {month: {'$match': 05}}
                           ])
```

the aggregates is not giving me any result.

I get response in postman,

```
{
    "count": 0,
    "sum": null,
    "avg": null,
    "min": null,
    "max": null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I prefer `collection.aggregate` over `aggregates`. Secondly, the `$match` pipeline was wrong. Lastly, even though it does work in ruby, don't write `05` ans some languages might interpret that as octal rather than decimal.

```
@events = Event.collection.aggregate([
                               {
                                   '$project': {
                                       _id: 1,
                                       created_at: 1,
                                       'month': {'$month': '$created_at'}
                                   },
                               },
                               {"$match" => {"month" => {'$eq': 5}}}
                           ]).to_a
```

Comment: how will I insert query elements in this? like we insert in where case.

Comment: Simple more `$match` elements. I found the documentation is very helpful on this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/